# On session start redirect - what will referrer be?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, global-asax

I'm using the global.asax's on_session_start() method to catch mobile user agents and redirect to a mobile version of a website. My question is:

On the mobile site if the user is redirected from the URL request blahblah.com/directory1 (remembering I'm using on_session_start()) - will the referrer be blahblah.com or blahblah.com/directory1?

Thanks

C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on_session_start()`  The referral will be `null`.